# symfony nelmio apidoc bundle: areas for yaml-defined method (token refresh from gesdinet)

Tags: symfony, refresh-token, nelmioapidocbundle

While upgrading to php8.1 I had to upgrade several modules of my current project, including gesdinet's refresh-token. A ghost method was present in my controller so I could document this api with annotations but it's not possible anymore. I managed to define the refreshtoken api method in nelmio_api_doc.yaml so I can still use it and test it from my sandbox page.

The problem here is that I have 5 areas in my api's documentation (and so, 5 sandbox pages) but the refresh_token method appear in every single one of them instead of only one.
I tried to insert various flavors and syntax of

```
areas:
    - front
```

in the configuration file but it doesn't seems to work.

Does anyone know how to restrict it the same way it was done with annotations but with the yaml file ? (nelmio's documentation is clearly lacking on the subject)

the "packages/nelmio_api_do.yaml" file

```
nelmio_api_doc:
    documentation:
        info:
            title: "API documentation"
            version: '%version%'
        sandbox:
            request_format:
                method: accept_header
            accept_type: application/json
            body_format:
                formats: [ form, json ]
                default_format: form
        paths:
            /api/front/token/refresh:
                post:
                    tags:
                        - Authentication
                    summary: Refresh token mechanism
                    parameters:
                        refresh_token:
                            in: formData
                            name: refresh_token
                            type: string
                    responses:
                        '200':
                            description: OK
                            schema:
                                type: object
                                properties:
                                    token:
                                        type: string
                                    refresh_token:
                                        type: string
                        '401':
                            description: An authentication exception occurred.
                    security: [ ]
    areas:
        default:
            path_patterns: [ ^/api/test/default ]
        front:
            path_patterns: [ ^/api/front ]
```

in advance thanks for your ideas.
(php 8.1 / symfony 5.4 / nelmio 3.10.1)

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind guys, I eventually found the solution.
I was trying to follow what I saw for defining paths in the yaml file but while I tried to insert it in

nelmio_api_doc->documentation->paths->[the_method_path] (which works)

the right way to do this and condition the method to an area is:

nelmio_api_doc->documentation->areas->[your_area_name]->paths->[the_method_path]

so now the file looks like:

```
nelmio_api_doc:
    documentation:
        info:
            title: "API documentation"
            version: '%version%'
        sandbox:
            request_format:
                method: accept_header
            accept_type: application/json
            body_format:
                formats: [ form, json ]
                default_format: form
        
    areas:
        default:
            path_patterns: [ ^/api/test/default ]
        front:
            path_patterns: [ ^/api/front ]
            paths:
                /api/front/token/refresh:
                    post:
                        tags:
                            - Authentication
                        summary: Refresh token mechanism
                        parameters:
                            refresh_token:
                                in: formData
                                name: refresh_token
                                type: string
                        responses:
                            '200':
                                description: OK
                                schema:
                                    type: object
                                    properties:
                                        token:
                                            type: string
                                        refresh_token:
                                            type: string
                            '401':
                                description: An authentication exception occurred.
                        security: [ ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

```
nelmio_api_doc:
    areas:
        oauth:
            path_patterns:
              - /oauth
            documentation:
                basePath: /
                info:
                    title: oauth api
                    description: oauth documentation
                paths:
                    /oauth/v2/token:
                        post:
                            tags:
                                - Authentication
                            produces:
                                - application/json
                            parameters:
                                -   name: client_id
                                    in: formData
                                    required: true
                                    type: string
                                -   name: username
                                    in: formData
                                    required: true
                                    type: string
                                    example: 'test@test.fr'
                                -   name: password
                                    in: formData
                                    required: true
                                    type: string
                                    example: 'password'
                                -   name: grant_type
                                    in: formData
                                    required: true
                                    type: string
                                    example: 'password'
                            responses:
                                200:
                                    description: Login successful
                                    schema:
                                        type: object
                                        properties:
                                            access_token:
                                                type: string
                                            expires_in:
                                                type: integer
                                            token_type:
                                                type: string
                                                example: 'bearer'
                                            scope:
                                                type: string
                                                example: null
                                            refresh_token:
                                                type: string
                                403:
                                    description: Login failed
                                    schema:
                                        type: array
                                        properties:
                                            error:
                                                type: string
                                            error_description:
                                                type: string
        default:
            path_patterns:
              - /address
            documentation:
                basePath: /
                info:
                    title: default API
                    description: default API documentation
                paths:
                    /address:
                        get:
                            tags:
                                - address
                            summary: OK - List address types
                            produces:
                                - application/json
                            parameters:
                                -   name: access_token
                                    type: string
                                    in: query
                                    required: true
                                    description: API access token
                            responses:
                                200:
                                    description: Returned when successful
                                    schema:
                                        items:
                                            $ref: "#definitions/AddressEntity"
                                        type: array
                                    examples:
                                        application/json:
                                            data:
                                                -   type:   adress type
                                                    id:     M
                                                    attributes:
                                                        id: M
                                                        label: Main Address
                                401:
                                    description: Bad access token
```